# What is this insect from Brazil

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: Small 'cicanda' from east Brazil taken in October 2017]

Im assuming 'cicada' with this insect but which one ? Small size- c1c-2 cm -

Comment: A better assumption would be "planthopper" (superfamily Fulgoroidea), but beyond that I admit to not having a guess.

Comment: I think you're right ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [neotropical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neotropical_realm) [leafhopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leafhopper) belongs to the subfamily Coelidiinae. According to [this publication](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/rbzool/v17n4/v17n4a04.pdf) though, there are 25 genera & over 75 different species, and so, I'm having a difficult time narrowing it down from there (my current best guess would be genus *Jikradia*).

[image]

If I'm not mistaken, this insect is displaying an [alarming signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alarm_signal) by spreading its wings like that.. it must have felt threatened by you when you were taking the picture (assuming that it wasn't already like that when you approached it).

For more information on this subfamily, I strongly suggest that you explore the text of the [previously linked publication](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/rbzool/v17n4/v17n4a04.pdf), as it contains great information regarding the various tribes of subfamily Coelidiinae, including distribution, origin, host plants, a bit of history, and so forth.

---

[image]

Comment: Brillient - it was 'alarmed' when i first noticed it ( probably more alarmed after afew bright flashes hit its eyes )